# Expectation of iid random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value

$X$  is a discrete random variable with mass function, $a(i), i\in Z^{+}$. $Y_{1},Y_{2},⋅⋅⋅,Y_{n}$ are independent identically distributed discrete r.v.   with mass function $b(i),i\in Z^{+}$.  Assume $a(i),b(i)>0,∀i$. Let $h $ is function from $ R$ to $R$. Define $T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a(Y_{k})h(Y_{k})}{b(Y_{k})} $ Then find expected value of $T$.
Please tell how to proceed.

Comment: What is the meaning of $p(Y_k)$ and $q(Y_k)$?

Comment: $p(i)$ and $q(i)$ are mass functions. I don't understand your question.- @SextusEmpiricus

Comment: Why do you use $Y_k$ in place of the argument $i$ in these mass functions $p(i)$ and $q(i)$? Such expressions are not typical, so maybe you could explain in words what the meaning of them is.

Comment: What you currently have is effectively a single function $f(Y_k)$ of the variable $Y_k$ defined by $$f(x) = \frac{p(x)h(x)}{q(x)}$$ and not a product of iid random variables.

Comment: It means $p(Y_{k}=i )$

Comment: It can be that you meant to use the probabilities. It looks like the average of the likelihood ratio. But maybe you can explain better where this problem comes from and where exactly your problem is. Where is it that you do not know how to proceed? It does not look like a product of variables, so is your title wrong or did you describe the problem wrong?

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Answer (score 1):

The expected value of the mean of a sample of iid variables is equal to the expected value of a single variable.

$$E\left[ T \right] = E\left[ \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a(Y_{k})h(Y_{k})}{b(Y_{k})}\right] =  E\left[ \frac{a(Y_{k})h(Y_{k})}{b(Y_{k})}\right]$$

To compute the mean of a function of a discrete variable use a sum over all possible values values of $i$ that the variable $Y_k$ can take (in the sum denoted by $\forall i$)

$$E(f(Y_k)) = \sum_{\forall i} b(i)f(i)$$

In your case the function is

$$f(i) = \frac{a(i)h(i)}{b(i)}$$

So you compute

$$E(f(Y)) = \sum_{\forall i} q(i) \frac{a(i)h(i)}{b(i)} = \sum_{\forall i}  a(i)h(i)$$